# clang-cl error: lld-link : error : undefined symbol: __divti3

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang-cl

When compile int128 division method with clang-cl (Clang-11.0 and MSVC2019), it occurs this error.
Code like:

```
__int128 a, b;
auto c = a / b;
```

and compiler outputs:

```
1>lld-link :error : undefined symbol: __divti3
1>>>> referenced by <path>\int128.h:594
```

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to link your executable with `clang_rt.builtins-x86_64.lib`.
You can find it in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\<Version>\lib\x64
```

Comment: GCC and Clang only support 128-bit integers in 64-bit mode, even in Linux. It's not because of the calling convention because large structs can be still be returned via a hidden pointer

Comment: Thanks, I added it from LLVM and works perfectly fine:
`C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\13.0.0\lib\windows\clang_rt.builtins-x86_64.lib`